Detect Objects & Gaps In A Shelf While Analyzing Shelf images using Pretrained Model of Azure Vision AI
I am doing SHELF PRODUCT RECOGNITION wherein the webApp (built using flask) analyzes shelf images using pretrained model of Azure Vision AI. I have using an Azure VM instance for this.
I need to detect Objects as well as the empty areas i.e. the gaps between these objects.
The following code of app.py marks the detected objects and the gaps between them:
import os
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models import VisualFeatureTypes
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/uploads/'

# Initialize Azure Computer Vision client
endpoint = os.getenv('AZURE_COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT')
key = os.getenv('AZURE_COMPUTER_VISION_KEY')
computervision_client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(key))

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    """
    Preprocess the image to detect edges.
    """
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150)
    return edges

def analyze_image(filepath):
    """
    Analyze the uploaded image using Azure Computer Vision and detect objects,
    and empty areas.
    """
    with open(filepath, "rb") as image_contents:
        results = computervision_client.analyze_image_in_stream(image_contents, visual_features=[VisualFeatureTypes.objects])

    image = cv2.imread(filepath)
    height, width, _ = image.shape

    empty_areas = []
    bounding_boxes = []

    # Analyze detected objects
    confidence_threshold = 0.5
    shelves = {}
    num_shelves = 5
    for obj in results.objects:
        if obj.confidence > confidence_threshold:
            left = int(obj.rectangle.x)
            top = int(obj.rectangle.y)
            right = left + int(obj.rectangle.w)
            bottom = top + int(obj.rectangle.h)
            bounding_boxes.append((left, top, right, bottom))
            row_key = (top // (height // num_shelves))
            if row_key not in shelves:
                shelves[row_key] = []
            shelves[row_key].append((left, top, right, bottom))

    # Detect empty areas between objects
    gap_threshold = 50
    for row_key, objects in shelves.items():
        objects.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
        for i in range(len(objects) - 1):
            _, _, right1, _ = objects[i]
            left2, _, _, _ = objects[i + 1]
            gap_width = left2 - right1
            if gap_width > gap_threshold:
                empty_areas.append((right1, row_key * (height // num_shelves), left2, (row_key + 1) * (height // num_shelves)))

    # Create an output image with bounding boxes
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    # Draw bounding boxes for objects
    for (left, top, right, bottom) in bounding_boxes:
        rect = plt.Rectangle((left, top), right - left, bottom - top, edgecolor='g', facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rect)

    # Draw bounding boxes for empty areas
    for (left, top, right, bottom) in empty_areas:
        rect = plt.Rectangle((left, top), right - left, bottom - top, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rect)

    # Save the output image
    result_filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'result_' + os.path.basename(filepath))
    plt.savefig(result_filepath)
    plt.close()

    return {
        'bounding_boxes': bounding_boxes,
        'empty_areas': empty_areas,
        'image_url': result_filepath
    }

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    """
    Handle the upload of the image and display analysis results.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file:
            filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)
            file.save(filepath)
            results = analyze_image(filepath)
            return render_template('result.html', results=results)

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)

The other files are index.html and result.html.
These files, combined with the updated app.py, will now handle object detection and gap detection. However, I am not able to correctly identify and mark all the objects and then detect the gaps between them.
The image being used for analysis has been attached. Following is the link for reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/how-to/shelf-analyze
What could be the additional changes that I can make in the analyze_image function to correctly identify the gaps between the objects?



Consider fine-tuning a model specific to the shelf images. Refine the method to detect gaps more accurately, taking into account overlapping objects and smaller gaps that might be missed.
Fine tune the model with a larger number of dataset labelled on empty places using azure ml labelling tool. Refer this doc1, doc2

Here I highlighted the image and increased contrast to get brighter and it help to detect the object effectively.

Project structure:
shelf-recognition/
│
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── templates/
│   ├── index.html
│   └── result.html
├── static/
│   ├── uploads/
│   └── css/
│       └── style.css
└── .env

requirements.txt:
flask
azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision
msrest
opencv-python-headless
matplotlib
python-dotenv

templates/index.html:
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload Image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload Image for Shelf Product Recognition</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

templates/result.html:
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Analysis Result</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Analysis Result</h1>
    <div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + results['image_url']) }}" alt="Result Image">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Detected Objects:</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for box in results['bounding_boxes'] %}
            <li>{{ box }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <h2>Empty Areas:</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for area in results['empty_areas'] %}
            <li>{{ area }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Application running successfully:

Uploading image:

Result:

